# Is there a way to count the number of blocks a player steps on?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way I can count the number of blocks a player steps on during gameplay and display it in some kind of *scoreboard*?

Comment: Are you asking that we make this system *for* you or...?

Comment: No, I just wanted someone Told me have any way to do this

Comment: I can't quite understand. Are you asking for someone to tell you how to do this? Because, in a sense, this still requires us to make it for you. At least provide us with some existing commands of yours to review.

Comment: @Texenox - I think the OP is trying to count the number of steps for each player. I've posted an edit suggestion to that extent. Also, by *have a way* he means *Is there a way?*.

Comment: I think I did not express myself well, wanted to know if you have some kind of command to do something similar to what crossy road or a mobile application of its kind in minecraft because I was charting about this style that the player will walk and it becomes increasingly faster, harder and was wondering if I was to do something like: Your last score or something [I'm brazilian , so , sorry if has an english error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tracked stat for distance travelled: `stat.walkOneCm`, which will let you know how far the player has walked in blocks/100.